# Lasso regression model has convergence warnings with GridSearchCV

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, gridsearchcv, lasso-regression

Here is the code that I have:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import Lasso
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
import numpy as np

alpha_space = {'alpha': np.logspace(-4, 0, 50)}
lasso = Lasso(normalize=True,  tol=0.0001)
grid_search_lr = GridSearchCV (lasso, alpha_space, cv=3, scoring="neg_mean_squared_error")
grid_search_lr.fit(X_tr, y_tr)

print(grid_search_lr.best_params_)
print(np.sqrt(-grid_search_lr.best_score_))
```

But when I go to run it, I get at least 20 of these warnings before the answer:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/linear_model/_coordinate_descent.py:476: ConvergenceWarning: Objective did not converge. You might want to increase the number of iterations. Duality gap: 8451216620580.201, tolerance: 12888767617.309622
```

positive)

What should I do in order to fix these warnings or prevent them?

Answer (score 1):

The `Lasso` estimator uses an iterative algorithm to solve the optimization problem. The iterative algorithm stops when it reaches the required level of convergence (set with the tolerance `tol`). To avoid having the algorithm perform too many iterations (and possibly never stop), the algorithm also stops when it has performed a maximum number of iteration (`max_iter`). In this case, it raises a warning that it failed to reach the required level of convergence.

To avoid the convergence warning, you can either:

- increase the tolerance `tol` (to require a less strict convergence level)
- increase the maximum number of iteration `max_iter` (to spend more time finding the convergence level)